# Wordpress Media Library - async-upload.php stuck at Crunching…

Tags: wordpress, upload, media

Inside Wordpress(v3.6) when uploading images with Media Library process is stuck at Crunching… with Status Code: 403 Forbidden. The only change before this problem occurred, WP sites was migrated to SSL protocol. Before this problem many images was uploaded with no problem.

The problem remains if I remove SLL for domain or even upgrade Wordpress to latest version 4.7. The path for uploading images is temporary set to 777. Image is even created inside this folder, just process is stuck at Crunching... And image is not listed inside "Media list".

To make problem more strange, I installed clean copy of WP on same server, just used other sub domain. Here uploading works normal. So server PHP settings cannot be blamed.

Any clues how to fix this issue?

Comment: Check if mod_security is enabled for the problematic domain or subdomain.

Comment: mod_security is not enabled on neither domains. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look for duplicates or ID=0 in your wp_posts table. I my case I did a server swap and during the DB transfer using find and replace it created duplicates. If you have any you would want to delete them. Just review the results first.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = '0' AND post_type = 'attachment';
```

OR

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) c FROM wp_posts GROUP BY ID HAVING c > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This was linked to an `auto_increment` issue on the database in my case.

Here's what fixed it for me:

```
DELETE FROM wp_termmeta  WHERE meta_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_terms  WHERE term_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_term_taxonomy  WHERE term_taxonomy_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_commentmeta  WHERE meta_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_comments  WHERE comment_ID=0;
DELETE FROM wp_links  WHERE link_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_options  WHERE option_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta  WHERE meta_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_users  WHERE ID=0;
DELETE FROM wp_posts  WHERE ID=0;
DELETE FROM wp_usermeta  WHERE umeta_id=0;

ALTER TABLE  wp_termmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(meta_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_terms ADD PRIMARY KEY(term_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_term_taxonomy ADD PRIMARY KEY(term_taxonomy_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_commentmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(meta_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_comments ADD PRIMARY KEY(comment_ID);
ALTER TABLE  wp_links ADD PRIMARY KEY(link_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_options ADD PRIMARY KEY(option_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_postmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(meta_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_users ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID);
ALTER TABLE  wp_posts ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID);
ALTER TABLE  wp_usermeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(umeta_id);

ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta CHANGE meta_id meta_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_terms CHANGE term_id term_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy CHANGE term_taxonomy_id term_taxonomy_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_commentmeta CHANGE meta_id meta_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_comments CHANGE comment_ID comment_ID  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_links CHANGE link_id link_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_options CHANGE option_id option_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta CHANGE meta_id meta_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_users CHANGE ID ID  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts CHANGE ID ID  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta CHANGE umeta_id umeta_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

As taken from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225641/wordpress-database-lost-auto-increment)